# Ubuntu WSL2 auto shutdown after 3 days

Tags: 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running TVHeadend in 2 Ubuntu 20.04 instances in WLS2 and I noticed they auto terminate after 3 days. Is there any way to override this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

If windows is terminating something at set interval then the first thing to check out would be "Task Schedular". Open it, and go to Microsoft/Windows/Windows Subsystem for Linux and check if any tasks are there, and if they are, do they have the option "Stop the task if it runs longer then 3 days" selected.

If nothing is there, check the root in Task schedule, TVHeadend might have a task there.

If still no luck, can you check the syslog just before WSL2 terminates, and if there is anything relevent post here so we can help.  Also check Event viewer for the time that WSL2 closes, and see if any events generated then may give you a hint of what is causing WSL2 to terminate.

Comment: No, nothing relevant shows. I think it is designed like this unfortunately.

Comment: anything in your cron?

Comment: No, everything is started from Windows startup....Just TVHeadend batch file ```powershell.exe wsl -u root service tvheadend start
powershell.exe wsl -d TVH_2 -u root service tvheadend start```

Comment: From cmd prompt start wsl in the shell, in the shell start tvheadend.  This will rule in or out powershell being the issue.